# JUnit Could not launch the JUnit plug-in tests. why?

Tags: java, tdd, junit4

First time I am trying Junit and I am following below link:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/JUnit/article.html

When I run my testClass as Run-As-> Junit Test. It says below thing.
Please help me in figure it out.

```
Could not launch the JUnit plug-in tests because project 'SalesTax'
 is not a plug-in project.
```

SalesTax: Is the Project Name
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you did create an Eclipse 'jUnit Plugin Test' launch configuration which is designed to run Eclipse plugins jUnit tests (in some kind of mocked eclipse environment).

Try to create a simple 'jUnit' launch configuration instead.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion - Follow the tutorial.  type in the (3-line) example "MyClassTest" from the tutorial.  Verify that you can get the tutorial working.  Post back with any questions about the tutorial.

Once you get one complete example working, end-to-end (your code, your JUnit test code, and successfully building and executing at least one JUnit test in your IDE), then try to get your "SalesTax" project working.

Q: I presume you're using Eclipse, correct?  Eclipse 3.7?

PS:

Here's another good tutorial:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-junit4/

Comment: I am using Eclipse Version: 3.6.2